# SQL Developer - Days between two specific records

Tags: sql, oracle

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vREY.jpg

I have included an example in above link.  Can you assist with helping me find the days between each ID IF the TYPE is 'C' and the TYPE_ID is 123?

For example -- The number of days between ID 313031 is 1,146 days (between 2/20/2018 and 1/1/2015) since we would be ignoring the other ID because it has a TYPE A.

Comment: Most people here want sample data and the expected result as formatted text, not images or links to images.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Provide more details

Comment: @jarlh Thanks. This is my first post, so they would not allow me to attach anything. They only allowed the link.

Comment: You don't need to attach anything, simply edit your question. Write sample data in proper columns. When done, mark that part and click `{}` - done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to determine the records you want compared. You could for instance use MIN(date) and MAX(date), but this really depends on your data.

Next, to determine the difference you can simply subtract the dates

So for instance, assuming you want to compare the first and last date for a given ID:

```
Select ID, 
Min(Date), 
MAX(Date),
Min(Date) - MAX(Date) as difference_in_days
From your_table
WHERE TYPE = 'C' and  TYPE_ID = 123
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work   :

```
select id,max1-min1  from (select max(date) as max1,min(date) as min1,id from tablename 
where type='C' group by id )
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. Can you show a way to show the number of days between each date (without the max)? Thanks!

Comment: number of days between each date??? which two dates you want ?? because your table has many dates??

Comment: For example, ID 313032 -- the difference between 1/1/2015, 1/21/2016, and 3/20/2018

Comment: @D.SQL `select id,max1-min1  from (select max(date) as max1,min(date) as min1,id from tablename 
where type='C' group by id )  where id=313032;` simply filter the above query by id!!!!

Comment: Thank you! But that does not show all the dates in the rows, just the min and max. Can it show each date and the dates between each row?

Comment: @D.SQL  so when three dates are present you need two outputs two differences isnot it??

Comment: yes! but that query is only pulling the difference between 3/20/2018 and 1/1/2015

Comment: create a temp table that has the valid (type = 'C') ID's and dates. Add a rownumber - partition by ID, order by date. Next, join this table on itself, using id = id and rownr = rownr-1. This will offset the dates by 1 record, so now you can do the datediff.